# Unable to display Firestore timestamp with toDate() in Angular template

Tags: angularjs, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code that get the data from `Accounts` collection:

```
    db.collection("Accounts").get().then((querySnapshot) => {
        if (!querySnapshot.empty) {
            $scope.accounts = querySnapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data());
            $scope.$apply();
        }
    });
```

[image: Firestore with DateJoined timestamp]

Below is my HTML:

```
    <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="account in accounts">
            <!-- More other columns with data here -->
            <td>{{ account.DateJoined.toDate() }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
```

But the result comes out **empty**. I do have data for the `DateJoined` field showing in my Firebase console. All other columns are able to show the data except the timestamp fields. May I know how can I display the Firestore timestamp field on Angular template? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using toDate() and [Angularjs date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date)

```
{{account.DateJoined.toDate() | date: 'dd/MM HH:mm'}}
```

Comment: Still **empty** after changing to `<td>{{ account.DateJoined.toDate()  | date: 'DD MMM yyyy' }}</td>`.

Comment: Cab you please share the DateJoined you get in your console? Thanks!

Comment: I've added a screenshot showing the `DateJoined` field with data on Firebase console.

Comment: Oops... Sorry, wrong spelling on field name, should be `DateJoined` and not `DataJoined`. Your answer is working, thanks a lot!

Comment: But looks like the **Angular date filter** does not support capital letter `DD`. Small letter `dd` works anyway. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, you are right! Updated the answer, thanks for mentioning!

Answer (score 1):

my own experience is, it is a bit difficult do deal direct firebase with angular 1.x because of both scope is different so.

please try to use  below angular plugins for a deal with firebase and angular1.x
https://github.com/firebase/angularfire/blob/master/docs/quickstart.md

Comment: I did use the `AngularFire` library: `<script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/2.3.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>`. FYI, I'm using `Firestore` in this example. Thanks.